# OCaml : issue with exceptions

Tags: exception, types, constructor, ocaml, caml-light

I wrote a program to evaluate the reverse polish notation in OCaml but I've had some troubles when I added the gestion of exception.

Here my code :

```
open Stack

type lexeme = 
  | Nombre of float
  | Op_binaire of (float -> float -> float)
  | Op_unaire of (float -> float)

exception Syntax_Error

let evalue lst = 
  let pile = create () in 
  let rec aux = function
  | [] -> let rep = pop pile in
            try 
              pop pile; 
              raise Syntax_Error with 
            Empty -> rep
            | Nombre a :: q -> push a pile; aux q
            | Op_unaire f :: q -> 
                let a = pop pile in 
                push (f a) pile; 
                aux q
            | Op_binaire f :: q -> 
                let a = pop pile in 
                let b = pop pile in 
                push (f a b) pile; 
                aux q
  in 
  try 
    aux lst 
  with 
  | Empty -> raise Syntax_Error
```

The console return the error message :

```
Line 9, characters 12-14:
9 | | (Nombre a)::q -> push a pile ; aux q
                ^^
Error: This variant pattern is expected to have type exn
       The constructor :: does not belong to type exn
```

Can someone help me please ? I think the probleme is about the syntax specificity of OCaml because I've seen a similar program on Caml Light which works perfectly.

Comment: Not knowing what `create`, `pop`, and `pile` actually look like, I'm going to take a mildly educated guess that `pile` is basically a stack, and you are throwing the `Empty` exception when `pile` is empty. Rather than this approach, you may want to consider using the `option` type so that `pop` can return `None` when `pile` is empty.

Comment: unrelated but you can pass the stack (a list) as a second argument to aux, making your code functional (no need for the Stack module)

Answer (score 3):

In OCaml after `try ... with` there can be a series of pattern matches against different exceptions.

This means that the `|` after your first `with` is interpreted as a continuation of this list of exception patterns rather than a continuation of the list of patterns for `function`.

In short, you should parenthesize the first `try ... with` (or surround with `begin .. end` which is equivalent to parentheses).

Change this:

```
| [] -> let rep = pop pile in
        try pop pile; raise Syntax_Error
        with Empty -> rep
```

To this:

```
| [] -> let rep = pop pile in
        begin
        try pop pile; raise Syntax_Error
        with Empty -> rep
        end
```

As a side comment, you should lay your code out more readably, especially when asking for help on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly ! Otherwise, what do you implie with make my code more readably ? Make it less large ? Add comments alongside the code ? I'm sorry if my first question on StackOverflow was difficult to read

Comment: I'm just talking about the layout. On my screen it's much too wide and not indented systematically. If you start to do a lot of OCaml coding you can use a formatting tool to lay it out for you. (Just a side comment.)